# Smooth interpolation plus distance from array of 2D points in Java / Android

Tags: java, android, math, interpolation, smoothing

I have array of 2d points filled with random points

```
float mPosX[] = new float[n]; //n=~ 2000
float mPosY[] = new float[n];
```

distance between each pair is irregular.

for example

```
mPosX[1] = 100;
mPosY[1] = 100;

mPosX[2] = 200;
mPosY[2] = 300;

mPosX[3] = -50;
mPosY[3] = 100;
```

What i need to achieve is

1. Make them look smoother - interpolate first ( i have tried using bezier splines but it is too slow in real time )
2. Find points on interpolated result from beginning to end every x distance

what is the fastest possible solution for this ? ( Android )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Point Sequence Interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107598/point-sequence-interpolation)